# computing cartesian coordination from image pixel

Tags: c++, math, opencv

I have a robot arm that moves within a cartesian space. And I have a camera over that space.
I need to compute, given a pixel in the image of the camera, its equivalents in cartesian space.

Do i need calibration of the camera? And how can I use it if yes?

Comment: What you want is pespective to world view projection. Not sure, but this one might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192886/perspective-to-world-space-inverse-projection

Comment: Of course you need camera calibration matrix!

Comment: A pixel in a 2D image will represent a ray in 3D space - so you need the equivalent ray, yes?

Comment: @roger_rowland yes I need that

Comment: Ok - take a look here for starters - http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT9/node2.html

Comment: thanks, i will have a look at it

Comment: You can also wiki Homography.

Comment: But calibrate your camera! you'll also get better precision!

Comment: i have already calibrated it, and my arm has a catersian referee

Comment: You will need the calibration for depth information to resolve ambiguity. Learn topic of projective/perspective transformations. Calibration is actually determining parametric part of homogeneous coordinates.